# How to access terms under custom taxonomy archive

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming, custom-taxonomy, taxonomy-terms

I have a Custom Taxonomy called `movie-genres`

```
'rewrite' => array('slug' => 'movie-genres', 'with_front' => true) );
 register_taxonomy( 'movie-genres', array( 'movies' ), $args );
```

And I have a WP template hierarchy for the `Taxonomy` and it's associated `Terms` like below

```
archive.php
archive-movie-genres.php

taxonomy.php
taxonomy-movie-genres.php
taxonomy-movie-genres-action.php
```

Now when navigating in the browser I am able to see the CPTs listed for term of action like this

```
domain.com/movie-genres/action
```

but when landing at `movie-genres` to get the all terms listed under this taxonomy like

```
domain.com/movie-genres/
```

I am getting the `404` page in return!

As you can see I have the `archive-movie-genres.php` and `taxonomy-movie-genres.php` created. Why am I getting ended at `404`?

Comment: We can't know why a question does not get any answers, and sometimes it is just poor luck. However, I wonder if your question wording may have something to do with it. Consistently your questions are exceptionally needy, and they are phrased in a way that gives the whole task to the reader. There is no sense when reading your questions that you want to do any of the work at all.

Comment: Your questions have been repaired possibly some 100+ times now in this regard, but it has not changed the writing style, which makes me wonder how much effort you're willing to undertake yourself.